# Average PHP file size, or recommended limit?

Tags: php, html, upload, preprocessor

I quickly wrote this up, http://www.ionfish.org/php-shrink/ where a user uploads a .php file with comments and spaces in it, and it will "minify" it for small file-size.

It does exactly this: http://devpro.it/remove_phpcomments/ except it's web-based, and instant. You get a download prompt after you click upload, to save the processed file.

My questions:

- Is a 2-megabyte upload limit enough? Should I make it 4, 8, etc. ?
- Is the output (requires you test it with some random PHP) satisfactory, or should it be tweaked?
- Would there be any use for this for the general public, and should I add support to minify HTML, CSS, JS, and even C++ and Python etc. ?

EDIT: Changed to 250K for now, will see if it suffices.

Comment: A 2 megabyte PHP file is a scary thing to contemplate. I've never written one that even exceeds 10k, and that's fairly big.

Comment: Yeah, I've never gone over 50K. I will leave it at 250K then?

Comment: Can't say good/bad either way. It's entirely up to you what you want to allow.

Comment: For me, something like that would be more useful if you exposed a REST API so people could automate the minification of all their files as part of the build process without doing it manually in their build script. It wouldn't be that difficult to determine the mime types of the POSTed data and automatically minify appropriately (or expect a file type parameter). Then, you could always have a manual form like the one you provided that ran off of the REST API backend. Of course, **that might be more work than you're looking for**.

Comment: @rdlowrey - That's actually not a bad idea at all. Allow users to set their own applications to make direct requests to the server to process it. I could just release the script too, but I will indeed look into this. Thanks.

Comment: my best for a library i needed is 23k

Comment: Sorry I have to ask, but: What's the reasoning behind a minifier for source code nobody except the author and a maintainer will see? I see the sense for minimizing css, html, js and stuff, but php? I bet you wouldn't wanna do that to java, c, ... either?

Comment: @Cassy - Well, it started as a proof-of-concept thing. I'm writing an HTML shrinker now, and the point is to take up less room on the server and possibly make it a little faster to process so the disk isn't scanning over as much space.

Comment: @MarcB Quiver in fear at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36990701/file-is-too-large-phpstorm-laravel-project-controller

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A file that needs such a minification is proof of bad practice.

1. The file size of a single php file should never be a problem when using best practice.
2. You should not be uploading files during your deployment anyways. Instead you should be checking out files from your VCS and you don't want 'minified' files in your VCS.
3. Such a minification will not improve site performance either since every serious project uses opcode caching.

Conclusion: Such a service is not needed.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'll still finish the project because SOMEONE out there would want a site where the customer can't see the HTML comments.

Comment: What does that have to do with HTML comments?

Comment: As in, I'm adding functionality for a multitude of files, like HTML and JS. Possibly some non-web files like C and Python.

Comment: JS and CSS minification are a standard which is integrated in many services and libraries already. mod_pagespeed does that, the assetics bundle does that, etc. etc.

Comment: What I'm trying to say here is that you're reinventing the wheel. If you're doing it for learning purposes, go ahead!

Comment: Yes, originally intended for learning purposes. I'm not sure how far I want to go with this script, due to a new job and time availability, though.